# Modernist piano excerpt (Ravel? Debussy?) from "Dialogue entre Jean-Pierre Serre" video

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental, piano

I would like to know the name of the music at the beginning of the video

[Dialogue entre Jean-Pierre Serre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOv-ygSynRI).

I searched with Midomi, but got no result. My guess is that it might be a composition of Ravel or Debussy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This excerpt is from the piece "[Laideronnette, Impératrice Des Pagodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MSZKjaSOrw&t=40s)" by the French composer Maurice Ravel (from 0:40 in the Youtube link).